# Finding Questions asked by me

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I am using the following incredibly useful utility...

http://data.stackexchange.com

The following shows the posts started / answered by me.

```
select * from Posts where OwnerUserId = 139150
```

How do I restrict the search only to the questions asked by me? I do not want to find the posts where I have written an answer.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, you can also see your own questions in your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/139150/shantanuo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to filter based on the PostTypeId.  1 is for questions.

`select * from Posts where OwnerUserId = 139150 and PostTypeId = 1`

Comment: Thanks. But this does not show the title. I do not want to select the "Body" column. How to get the title in the query.

Comment: @shantanuo This does show the title, but you need to scroll far to the right to find it. If you want just the title, change `select *` to `select title`. Also, there is a typo. `OwnerUsedId` needs to be changed to `OwnerUserId`.